# Lumen rest-api delete route drops 405

Tags: javascript, http-headers, response, lumen

I have the following routes for my lumen rest-api

```
$app->configure('database');
$app->get('/', 'ApiController@index');
$app->post('/auth/login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1','namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($app)
{
    $app->get('users', function() use ($app) {
        $users = App\User::all()->toJson();
        echo $users;
    });

    //Uploads
    $app->post('users','ApiController@createUser');
    $app->post('uploads','ApiController@uploadFiles');
    $app->get('uploads','ApiController@getUploads');
    $app->get('download/{file}','ApiController@downloadFile');
    $app->put('uploads/{id}','ApiController@updateFile');
    $app->get('uploads/download/{file}','ApiController@downloadFile');
    $app->delete('uploads/{id}','ApiController@deleteFile');

    //Users
    $app->put('users/{id}','ApiController@updateUser');
    $app->delete('users/{id}','ApiController@updateUser');

});

$app->get('/{params:.+}', 'ApiController@index');
```

and when I try to access the delete method of user I get a response `405 Method Not Allowed`

here is my JavaScript which is triggering the action:

```
delete(id) {
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/v1/users',
            type: 'DELETE',
            data:{id: id},
            success: function(result) {
               console.log(result)
            }
        });
}
```

what I do wrong?

my app.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

 $app->withFacades();
 $app->register('Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider');
 $app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

// $app->middleware([
//    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

 $app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
//$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->register('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');

class_alias('Collective\Html\HtmlFacade', 'Html');

class_alias('Collective\Html\FormFacade', 'Form');

$app->register('Collective\Html\InjectVarsServiceProvider');

lumenUrlHost('file-drop.dev');

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
});

return $app;
```

Comment: Did you use Dingo? I suggest you also post your `bootstrap/app.php` file. I have this issue when I combine Dingo routing with Lumen routing for the same prefix.

Comment: Hi thanks for feedback I do not use Dingo, I added my app.php